# What is the correct way to save and edit a file in C# while using an .nsi install script?

Tags: c#, nsis

In my project, I have an xml file that stores a bunch of strings that the program reads and displays. What I want to happen is to build the program with the file, use the install script to create the installer (I already move all the .dll and .exe files to a bin folder for the script via post-build events) and then have the end user be able to access this file and have the program automatically load the file each time its run.

This is how I currently open the file. This looks in the debug folder but I want it to live in a persistent location.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("PowerManagers.xml");
```

My .nsi file:

```
!define FullName "Power Manager Safety Testing"
!define ProductName "Power Manager Safety Testing"
!define ProductExe "PowerManagerSafetyTesting.exe"

;--------------------------------
;Include Modern UI

!include "MUI.nsh"
!include "Framework .Net Install.nsh"
!include "Common Functions.nsh"
!include "Common Drivers.nsh"

ShowInstDetails show

!insertmacro Insert_System_Configuration

;--------------------------------
; The stuff to install
Section "${ProductName}" Sec_Id_Main

SectionIn RO
Call MainSectionInstall

; The files to use in this installer
File "..\..\bin\PowerManagerSafetyTesting\*.exe"
File "..\..\bin\PowerManagerSafetyTesting\*.dll"
File "..\..\bin\PowerManagerSafetyTesting\PowerManagers.xml"

SectionEnd

;---------


;---------

; Optional section (can be disabled by the user)
Section "Start Menu Shortcuts" Sec_Id_Start

Call StartMenuSection

SectionEnd

;---------

; Optional section (can be disabled by the user)
Section "Desktop Shortcuts" Sec_Id_Desktop

Call DesktopShortcutsSection

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;   Uninstaller

Section "Uninstall"

Call un.UninstallerSection

SectionEnd


;--------------------------------
;  Page descriptions
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SECDOTNET_ID} $(DESC_LONGDOTNET)
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec_Id_Main} "Installs the core files     required to run the ${ProductName}"
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec_Id_Start} "Installs short cuts to the start menu"
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${Sec_Id_Desktop} "Installs short cuts to the desktop"
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your XML file inside Windows data directory i.e. `C:\ProgramData\Your_App` and read from there inside your C# app and write the file in that path from your installer.

**C# program**

```
String strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
strPath += "\\Your_App\\PowerManagers.xml";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(strPath);
```

**NSIS script**

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellFolders" "Common AppData"
CreateDirectory "$0\Your_App"
SetOutPath "$0\Your_App"
File "..\..\bin\PowerManagerSafetyTesting\PowerManagers.xml"
```

Comment: I use, this registry reading method for my scripts and it works well on XP, 7, 8. If you have any code other than using plugins kindly share.

Comment: Google "shellfolders oldnewthing". Read the NSIS constants section in the documentation to find out how to do it correctly...

Comment: @Anders: I didn't find anything helpful. Could you give me the link or sample. Eager to know the NSIS Constant for AppData which works on XP, 7, 8.

Comment: @hypeni: SetShellVarContext all + $AppData